# Zabbix Discovery with External check JSON

Tags: json, bash, zabbix, discovery

Zabbix 3.2.5 in docker on alpine image (official build)

I have some problem with external script and returned JSON.
The script json_data.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Generate JSON data for zabbix
declare -i i
fields=$1
data=($2)
json=""
i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#data[*]} ]; do
    row=""
    for f in $fields; do
        row+="\"{#$f}\":\"${data[$i]}\","
        i+=1
    done
    json+="{${row%,}},"
done
echo "{\"data\":[${json%,}]}"
```

key string is:

```
json_data.sh["IP", "127.0.0.1 127.0.0.2 127.0.0.3"]
```

I test it with text item and have result

```
2539:20170515:095829.375 zbx_popen(): executing script
{"data":[{"{#IP}":"127.0.0.1"},{"{#IP}":"127.0.0.2"},{"{#IP}":"127.0.0.3"}]}
```

So script returns valid JSON but i still have error **Vallue Should be JSON** object in service discovery.
What wrong with that JSON?

---

[Template Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBqdC.png) In screenshot {$IPLIST} just macro = "127.0.0.1 127.0.0.2 127.0.0.3"

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smddJ.png)

Comment: Which version of Zabbix? Is this key used in the LLD rule? What's the LLD rule item type? Are you sure that error is from the latest version/invocation (have you waited for at least 10 minutes after making the latest changes)?

Comment: Sorry. Forget that. Zabbix 3.2.5

Comment: It don't go to the item because of error in discovery.

Comment: And i wait whole day, nothing changes.

Comment: I make custom script with `#!/bin/bash
echo { "data": [{ "{#IP}": "127.0.0.1"}, {"{#IP}": "127.0.0.2"}, {"{#IP}": "127.0.0.3"}]}`, and still have same error.

Answer (score 2):

This is bug. When `DebugLevel` is more than 3 Zabbix mix part of the debug output with the value data. Something like `zbx_popen(): executing script`.
Solution to reduce `DebugLevel` to 3 or lower, and wait until [ZBX-12195](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-12195) will be fixed.